# Result is ALWAYS false from getNativeDialogDidComplete in onComplete for Facebook MessageDialogBuilder in onActivityResult

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

On Android Facebook SDK 3.20 we have implemented the MessageDialogBuilder interface and the onComplete and onError events ARE invoked after the user interacts with the Messenger.

The user HAS logged into FaceBook using the FaceBook Login.  But we get NO results from getNativeDialogDidComplete (ALWAYS false) and getNativeDialogCompletionGesture (always NULL).

Has anyone on Android got this to return the result and completion gesture ?  We did setup the trackPendingDialogCall on the present.

We see it works on the Apple Facebook SDK.  Not sure what we are missing here or if this is an uncompleted item on Android Facebook SDK?